# How to save cakephp this request data in another field

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I have created a input field name `money` and there have a select option. If I select `debit` then money input data will save in `debit_money` field, If I select `credit` then money input data will save in `credit_money` field.

Add.ctp like this

Select field like

```
echo $this->Form->input('transaction_type', array(
            'empty' => 'Choose A Transaction Type',
            'options' => array('Debit', 'Creadit')
));
```

money input field

```
echo $this->Form->input('money',array('class'=>'form-control'));
```

In controller I have wrote below code

```
 if($this->request->data['Transaction']['transaction_type']==0)
    {
        $this->request->data['Transaction']['debit_money'] == $this->request->data['Transaction']['money'];

        if ($this->Transaction->save($this->request->data)) {
           $this->Session->setFlash(__('The transaction has been saved.'));
        }
   }
```

Here no data saving in `debit_money` field and also I didn't get any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First look at `['debit_money'] == $this->request` 
you use Equal [Comparison operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)  **==**
instead of [Assignment Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) **=**

Your code should look like this

```
$this->request->data['Transaction']['debit_money'] = $this->request->data['Transaction']['money'];
```

Comment: oh! Thanks ! Several time I have checked but this = ignore by my eyes !!